# iOS - removeFromSuperview crashes the app sometimes

Tags: ios

I have a page with a back button that takes me to an inbox. I do this in viewWillDisappear -

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [inboxToolbar removeFromSuperview ];
[inboxToolbar release];
```

}

If I do this a few times, the app crashes and the exception thrown is "unrecognized selector sent to instance". This happens very intermittently. Any thoughts on how to go about fixing / debugging it?

Comment: What kind of instance is it? Does the debugger show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the crash is accessing your `inboxToolbar` ivar, change your code to the following:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   [inboxToolbar removeFromSuperview ];
   [inboxToolbar release];
   inboxToolbar = nil;
}
```

This will ensure `inboxToolbar` does not keep a pointer to a deallocated object. You could also have other issues, would need to see the crash log and more of your code to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking whether it will respond to your method first...

```
if ([inboxToolbar respondsToSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]) {
    [inboxToolbar removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add an exception break point to see where it is being thrown, you probably are sending a message to an object that isn't of the class that you believe it to be, after you have stopped on the exception breakpoint, you can hover over the variable to see what classes they belong to.

if that doesn't help post the actual message and perhaps we can help more, could be iOS version issue, etc.